# EasyXDM passing data issue

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, easyxdm

I'm using rpc with XDM, and I can send simple data back and forth easily between child and parent window.

But it seems to be limited to simple strings and numbers. The demos on the site only use numbers.  When I try to send a json ecoded string, I get a cross domain error.   When I use cors, I can make ajax requests fine, but I can't display the child page in the iframe, because the data is returned and not rendered.

My question is, how can I render an iframe, and pass complex data back and forth. Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not pass a stringified object back and forth?  See `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` for more details.  Note that you will have to use a shim for IE7 and older.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's what I was trying to do, but it wasn't working.  I figured it out though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I wasn't stringifying correctly.  Good to know it works!

Comment: there is so few people that have worked with easyXDM. May you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203172/easyxdm-download-files-from-3rd-party-service please?